# Composing Nested Reducers on Same Level

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to have the following redux state managed by a `Person` reducer and an `Address` reducer:

```
{
  person: {
    name: 'John Doe',
    address: {
      street: '123 Main Street',
      ...
    }
}
```

I've tried using `combineReducer` and `reduceReducer`, but I'm not able to get the desired outcome.

Ideally, the person reducer manages the properties directly under it while address does the same.

What am I missing?

Comment: What have you got so far? Please share your code. BTW, You will find it easier if you flatten your state, so you will have a persons section of state and an addresses section, linked by ids.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for relationship between 2 reducers. You can consider [normalizing the state shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape).

Normalized `Person` reducer could look like:

```
{
  persons: {
    byId: {
      person1: {
        id: 'person1',
        name: 'John Doe',
        address: 'address1'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While the `Address` becomes:

```
{
  addresses: {
    byId: {
      address1: {
        id: 'address1',
        street: '123 Main Street',
        // ....
      }
    }
  }
}
```